# Get filepath from inputStream

Tags: android, image, file-io, inputstream

I am loading a picture from the gallery and setting it to a imageview, but I have a function that rotates the image and that function requires the images Uri. When I read in the picture from memory I use the following code

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
    }else{
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_FILE);
    }
```

then

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == SELECT_FILE){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = null;
            try {
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            }catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            final Bitmap rotatedImage = rotateBitmap(selectedImage, **image file path**);
            profilePic.setImageBitmap(rotatedImage);
        }
    }
}
```

The function `rotateBitmap()` needs the image's file path, which I do not know how to get...

Comment: There is no "file path". Your `rotateBitmap()` method needs to be rewritten, or you need to supply your own path to write to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cursor:

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, proj, null, null, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    String  file_path = cursor.getString(column_index);
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: Perfect - worked without a problem. Thanks A million!!

Answer (score 0):

using Uri you can get the path of the image ...
Try this code, might help you

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Use_Uri_Here, null, null, null, null); 
cursor.moveToFirst(); 
int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
String imagePath = cursor.getString(idx);
```